# Генерация палитры цветов с JS по rgb

Tags: javascript

Имеется вот [такой генератор](https://material.io/inline-tools/color/)
Можете выбрать там какой-нибудь яркий цвет. Обратите внимание, что там нумерация идёт от 900 и до 50. Цвет в кружке -- начальный цвет. Именно от него идёт генерация других цветом.

Нужен код по генерации точно такой же палитры. Мне удалось написать свою реализацию, но дело в том, что в моей реализации цвета только становятся темнее и светлее, а в примере по ссылке они ещё и оттенок немного меняют, а не просто затемняются или засветляются.

Сделала я свою реализацию со сдвигом цветом в `rgb`. К примеру, был цвет `rgb(150, 150, 150)` и я просто сдвигаю значения каждого канала и получаю, к примеру, следующее: `rgb(130, 130, 130)`. Тем самым начальный цвет стал темнее.

Но вся суть в том, что по ссылке выше работает какой-то другой алгоритм и меняются ещё и оттенки.

[может в самой либе это есть](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) но я там не нашла конкретно, что мне нужно. Вот здесь `/packages/mui-system/src/colorManipulator.js` но там, насколько я поняла, нет того, что нужно.

Comment: _«в моей реализации цвета только становятся темнее и светлее, а в примере по ссылке они ещё и оттенок немного меняют»_ - масло масляное, оттенок это есть светлота (lightness). Если подразумевалась насыщенность цвета (saturation), то она меняется переводом RGB►HSL/HSV►RGB, как и тон (hue). Это не так уж сложно, тем более что теории и формул в интернете куча ([вот например](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-07998-1_23.pdf) первое из гугла), как и готовых библиотек (просто используй поиск по npm и по github).

Comment: Ну и [готовое на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493060/12506088) тоже никто не прятал)) А как генерировать палитры - см. материалы по цветоведению в дизайне (они вроде включают теор.основы типа "что такое цвет", хотя хз, я рисовальщик а не дизайнер, но фундаментальные основы вроде общие).

Answer (score 0):

Почему не читаете  там названия палитры?

Наверно так:
COMPLEMENTARY
3. Комплементарные цвета

ANALOGOUS

2.Аналогичное сочетание цветов

TRIADIC

5.Триада

https://aipa.ru/content/34-garmonichnye-sochetaniya-cvetov-cvetovoj-krug-jokhanessa-ittena

Comment: Не, всё это не о том. Мне удалось изучить код по ссылке. Там всё очень сложно, формул тьма, а код ещё и минифицирован и это главная проблема. В общем, там под капотом работает нейронная сеть. Сворачиваемся господа))

Answer (score 0):

Господи…та нет там никакой нейронной сети.  Нужно хорошо поискать готовые цветовые схемы библиотек либо найти в литературе эти формулы как вам уже сказали выше.

Вот тут можно поиграть интерактив.
https://colorscheme.ru/
Судя по работе всех 6 схем там тригонометрия школьного уровня “повернуть точку на угол”. Непонятно почему не показано движение точек к центру и от центра. Задаем точку на круге базовый цвет, остальные точки получаем через матрицу поворота  в 2д.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Матрица_поворота](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)

x=x *cos(ang_rad)-y *sin(ang_rad)

y=x *sin(ang_rad)+y *cos(ang_rad)

Положительный угол крутит в одну строну, отрицательный в другую.
Потаскайте точку там, остальные просто прибавляют угол к текущей в одну и другую стороны. Осталось только нарисовать такой круг палитру и читать по нужным координатам цвет пикселя и вся цветовая схема, точней их там 6…значит все 6 схем.

Comment: Вы даже не представляете сколько мне пришлось пересмотреть разных генераторов. Не нашла ни одного где бы хотя бы что-то подобное было. Я ведь уже написала, что там машинное обучение. Даже в самом коде датасеты для обучения есть. Сами здесь посмотрите https://material.io/inline-tools/color/bundle.js и по ctrl+F вбейте вот это 94.67497003305085 и увидите там датасет для обучения. Может я ошибаюсь в чём то, но там много предварительно подготовленных цветов и по формулам и тем цветам ведутся расчёты.

Comment: Вы такой генератор не соорудите просто на синусах и косинусах. И мне не интересны все схемы, а только самая первая.

Answer (score 0):

«Не нашла ни одного где бы хотя бы что-то подобное было.”
Цвета с
https://material.io/inline-tools/color/
и
https://colorscheme.ru/
комплиментраные не совпадают. Видимо кто-то из них накрутил своего.
А мне кажется тут https://colorscheme.ru/ вполне симпатичные цвета. Похоже и строгих правил тут вообще нет раз можно раздвигать точки мышкой аж в 6 схемах  и алгоритм нагляден.
А тут и к центру можно двигать,
https://sebweo.com/ru/tsvetovoy-krug-online/
цвет похоже на https://material.io/inline-tools/color/

тест :

1)https://material.io/inline-tools/color/

2)https://sebweo.com/ru/tsvetovoy-krug-online/

1)вход  #ff0505 выход #05ffff
2)выход #05FFFF

1)вход  #05ff67 выход #ff059b
2) выход #FF059D

3)вход #050eff  выход #fff705
2) выход #FFF605
Очень близко и никакой магии.

“что там машинное обучение.»
Зачем…

“Вы такой генератор не соорудите просто на синусах и косинусах.”

Именно на углах и строят все 6 схем.
Вот тут
https://sebweo.com/ru/tsvetovoy-krug-online/
“тип комбинации цветов” тройной
Похоже сделали угол константа и вся разница, может и в том сайте так.

Answer (score 0):

Переводи RGB в HSL и по строкам крути L - lightness. По вертикали крути H - hue на сколько там крутится комплиментарные цвета. И переводи обратно.

Функции перевода можно взять тут https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256